# vb.net 2005: POST user data to an URL

Tags: vb.net

I need a solution to **post user data to an URL**. The project is in VB.Net 2005. The VB application will be running in user system and the data that will be filled by the user will be sent to an URL located in some other location.

### My code is mentioned below:

```
Imports System.Web 
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports system.Net 
Imports System.Text 


Private Sub btnGetData_Click()
    Dim r0 As String 
    Dim r1 As String 
    Dim r2 As String 
    Dim r3 As String 
    Dim r4 As String 
    Dim q As New Object 

    r0 = txtID.Text
    r1 = txtName.Text 
    r2 = txtClass.Text 
    r3 = txtAcad.Text 
    r4 = txtDateJoined.Text

    q = ("r0 = " + r0 + " & r1 = " + r1 + " & r2 = " + r2 + " & r3 = " + r3 + " & r4 = " + r4)
    q = ("http://localhost/test.php?" + q)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(q)
End Sub
```

-----------------------------

And I encountered with an error:
**NullReferenceException was handled**
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

-----------------------------

Please help to resolve the issue with a very simple solution.

Comment: Winforms doesn't have any `HttpContext.Current`. You would need to create an instance of `WebClient` and work with it. Just google around, you will find many examples.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, it worked.